# Water heater won’t lite - replaces thermopile

Tags: water-heater, gas

I replaced my thermopile after my water heater was displaying a 4 blink message (too hot). Now the pilot won’t light. What have I done wrong? Should I be concerned about continuing to mess with it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. You should [take our tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how the site operates. Also more info will help us to help you. Make and model # would be a good start.

Comment: What make and model is this water heater?

Comment: Two hot is usually not a thermocouple issue for a gas heater. The thermocouple sits in the flame and generates a voltage from the heat, some times it takes 30 seconds or more to get the thermocouple hot enough to open the valve. 

Follow the starting instructions but they are normally something like: turn the gas valve to pilot and hold in, light the pilot wait 30 seconds with the pilot burning, turn the valve quickly to heat , the two hot error may be a temp safety switch that must be reset . Check for that. Other than that we will need a model number to be of any real help.